# Why is the uploaded file Zip file is empty?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, zip

I'm uploading files using the jQuery [Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) and PHP. I uploaded a Zip file to the server, using `move_uploaded_file()`. It returned true, and then I unzipped the file to another folder in the server, copying existing files and folders to the directory. However, I cannot see the files inside the folder. Only the folder exists. Then I downloaded the uploaded file, and when I tried to unzip it locally, I got `The archive is either in unknown format or damaged`. The original Zip file is opening fine. I just don't get what happened to the archive. Please help me out.

Comment: have you listed the files in the folder after moving it, to check it's there and has size the same as the original

Comment: "Then i downloaded the uploaded file and when i try to unzip it locally i get The archive is either in unknown format or damaged." - so it is being uploaded. Delete it first and re-do it incase of premissions not allowing it to be overwritten.

Comment: It is being uploaded. But all the files inside the zip is missing.

Comment: I found the mistake. i have used fopen on the uploaded file mistakenly . When i removed that potion of code and process the whole thing, i can find correctly uploaded file. But what i don't understand is how could it lose content when its opened at the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Zip implementation differs from system to system. An archive created on windows might not be readable on linux. The archive might be valid actually.

Please provide specifics: how you created the archive, how you extracted it...

Comment: guitarlass is opening the zip on the same pc (upload to server then download back again) which implies a corruption somewhere. Try FTPing the zip, rather than jquery uploading , then unzipping it to check if kgb's answer is correct.

Comment: yupp i did it before. I used ftp to download and unziped though code. It works fine with ftp.

Answer (score 0):

By all means, you need to specify a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML form. Other wise your file will not be uploaded properly (or at all):

```
<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    File: <input type="file" name="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

According W3C specifications regarding the enctype: "*This attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value  "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the  INPUT element, type="file".*"

Comment: All these codes are already added , I don't think that even an empty zip file will be uploaded if `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is missing.